# IOS/Objective-C:EventKit EKReminders compared with EKEvents

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I a experimenting with EventKit and am confused by how events compare with reminders.

Do you need to obtain separate permission to access reminders and events?

I know there is such a thing as self.eventStore `requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder` and also  `requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent`

Here are methods for both.  But it seems excessive to have to ask for permission for things that are so closely related twice.

```
-(void)requestAccessToEvents{

    [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Store the returned granted value.
            self.grantedEvents = granted;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:granted] forKey:@"eventsAccessGranted"];

        }
        else{
            // In case of error, just log its description to the debugger.
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }
    }];
}
-(void) requestAccessToReminders
{

    [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil) {
             // Store the returned granted value.
             self.grantedReminders = granted;
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:granted] forKey:@"remindersAccessGranted"];

         }
         else{
             // In case of error, just log its description to the debugger.
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }

         if (granted)
         {
             importEvents * __weak weakSelf = self;
            //ensure code will be executed from the main queue
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 //  [weakSelf aMethodToUpdateUIFetchEvents];//method located in viewController
             });
         }
     }];
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There's only one question (which is good), not three. Have you read the documentation for `EKEventStore`?

Comment: Yes.  I've read the docs and also the guide with code samples to eventkit and can't find an explicit explanation of the difference between the two classes.  There is a separate plist key not only for events and reminders but also for calendars.  And there are the two methods above.  On the other hand, reminders inherit from events and it seems that it is a bit burdensome on the user to ask for permission multiple times for things that are so closely related.  So I was hoping someone would just know one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EKEntityTypeEvent` is for events that go to the user's calendar.

`EKEntityTypeReminder` is for reminders that go to the user's reminders.

Each requires its own request for permission. A user might allow access to one but not the other. Ignore that the APIs are similar and related. To the user, they are two completely different things.

Comment: Further to this topic, when would you need to request permission for EKCalendar?  It does not appear to be necessary for getting events and reminders from the calendar.

Comment: Correction.  I rechecked plist and it has two relevant privacy keys - reminders and calendar.  There is no separate one for events. Does the calendar key correspond to EKEvents?